# WiX setup has no localized texts in message boxes

Tags: wix

I'm creating a WiX setup with "en-US" and "sr-Latn-CS" localizations. "sr" stands for Serbian. All dialogs are localized just fine. I can see Serbian texts during setup. But if some message box pops out the text in it is still in English. See the picture below. Forms are localized, but message boxes are not. What should I do to have the message boxes localized too?

[image: English text in Serbian message box]

This particular text "Are you sure you want to cancel" has Id="Error1602" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\SDK\wixui\WixUI_en-us.wxl". Corresponding text does exist in corresponding file WixUI_sr-Latn-CS.wxl. It's just not used.

BTW, "-CS" is old designation and it should be sr-Latn-RS instead, but WiX toolset does not have the valid locale, and I don't want to bring all the texts into my project. It should works with -CS just as well.

Comment: Does your MSI have an `Error` table?

Comment: @Rob I don't know by heart. Out of office, but downloaded the latest public MSI, and opened it with Advanced Installer. Never used it before. There is no `Error` table in section called `Table Editor`.

Comment: @RobMensching there is no `Error` table in may latest DEV MSI as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Installer will provide error messages by default for the locales that it supports. If you want error messages in locales that the Windows Installer does not support natively, you can populate the Error table (use the `<Error/>` element in WiX) with your custom error messages.

Comment: So, the "-CS" was in fact the problem. When I changed "sr-Latn-CS" to "sr-Latn-RS" and LANGID 2074 to 9242 I got proper texts. I also had to copy WixUI_sr-Latn-CS.wxl to the project, with its culture again changed to "sr-latn-rs" to be able to compile. Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could create a [new issue in the WiX Toolset](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/new) with exactly details what you fixed. Or even better, [send a PR against wix4](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix4/) with the fixes. We don't have any experts in Serbian. :)